# Any way to change post/page status when editing page?

Tags: post-status

Pre-Gutenberg, in the “Status & Visibility” panel, there used to be a way to change a Post’s status from “Published” to “Draft” or “Pending Review” – is that just gone now? The only way I can see to change a Page/Post’s status now via Quick Edit on the main admin-list page.

That’s not ideal, as often it is far easier to navigate to a Page on the front-end and use the top Admin bar to ‘Edit Page’ vs having to find the page in the backend control panel.

I've posted this WordPress.org forums too, to see if we can get the functionality back in a future update, just figured I'd see if anyone here had a solution or suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing a page, click on the cog wheel in the upper right corner to ensure the sidebar displays.

There should be two tabs: `Document` and `Block`. Make sure `Document` is selected.

There is an accordion item called `Status & visibility`, among `Permalink`, `Discussion`, and `Page Attributes`.

If you click on `Status & visibility` to expand it, there is a `Visibility` item in there.

Clicking on the current visibility reveals radio buttons to select `Public`, `Private`, or `Password Protected`.

To change a page from `publish` to `draft`, take a look at the top right, to the left of the `Update` button. There is a link that says `Switch to draft`.

Once it's back in `draft`, under `Status & visibility`, there is now a checkbox above the `Move to trash` link that says `Pending review`, and if you check that, at the top you can now `Save as pending`.

Comment: Understood, but what I want to do is change the Status from "Published" to "Draft". I can't see any way to do that, except in Quick Edit mode on the main Pages/Posts lists page.

Comment: @Michelle I revised my answer-- sorry for missing those specifics. I didn't answer your question at all.

Comment: brilliant! Like so many "improvements" that one was very hard to find. Don't get me started on how much harder it is to View Page now ... :-) Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Michelle Haha, yes, it's definitely an "improvement" :)